# How to make sure user input is in $XX.XX format? Could also be in $XX format but program will convert it to a 2 decimal float

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I would like to make sure input from the user is in $XX or $XX.XX format. If it's in $XX then the program would change the $XX to $XX.00. Basically I want to get an amount in dollars and cents from the user, make sure that it is a float with decimal (if not, return an error message and ask for input again) and then confirm the amount is correct with the user. I'm just starting out so multiple techniques are welcome and an explanation on which would be best. Thank you in advance!!!

def income(company):

```
print("Do you have any income from", company, "today?")
ans = confirm()
delay(0.45)
if ans == True:
    total = input('What was your income from ' + company + ' today?\nIncome: $')
    while isinstance(total, (float, int)):
        print("Invalid amount! Please enter in $XX.XX format.")
        total = input('Income: $')
        if isinstance(total, (float, int)):
            return total
    print('Is $', total ,'correct?')
    totalconfirm = confirm()
    while totalconfirm == False:
        total = float(input('Enter the correct amount: $'))
        totalconfirm = confirm()
elif ans == False:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print out the total in the format XX.XX (or X.XX or XXX.XX etc.) with `"{:.2f}".format(total)`. This formats it as a float to two decimal places. You do not need to apply this formatting to any of the math, just the printing.

Checking if inputs are valid numbers can be done with

```
try:
   val = float(userInput)
except ValueError:
   # your code here
```

Comment: Would this deny any characters that aren't integers?

Comment: This assumes that `total` is a number. If you want to check if inputs are integers, you can use the edit I just added